The UR5 robot does not appear in the gazebo

ROS2 version: Humble
Ubuntu version: 22.04

I'm studying URDF now, and I'm trying to put UR5e on the Gazebo simulation, but it's not going well, so I have a question.
I downloaded the package provided in Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description and created my own launch file.
The launch file provided in the link above does not run gazebo node and spawn node, so I created a launch file that added them. Here is the code I added to the view_ur.launch.py provided in the link above.
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, ExecuteProcess, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

# gazebo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gazebo_node = IncludeLaunchDescription(
PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
PathJoinSubstitution([
FindPackageShare("gazebo_ros"),
"launch",
"gazebo.launch.py"])
]),
launch_arguments={"verbose": "false"}.items(),
)

# spawn robot in gazebo --------------------------------------------------------------------------
spawn_entity = Node(
package="gazebo_ros",
executable="spawn_entity.py",
arguments=[
"-topic", "robot_description",
"-entity", "ur_robot"
],
output="screen",
)

nodes_to_start = [
joint_state_publisher_node,
robot_state_publisher_node,
rviz_node,
gazebo_node, # modification
spawn_entity, # modification
]

When I run this code, I don't see the ur5e robot, but it is added to the model next to it.
Below is the information I get when I run it in a terminal window.
 park@park:~/ur_test2$ ros2 launch ur_description view_gazebo_ur.launch.py ur_type:=ur5e

[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/park/.ros/log/2024-04-20-20-21-23-768616-park-17446

[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO

[INFO] [joint_state_publisher_gui-1]: process started with pid [17448]

[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [17450]

[INFO] [rviz2-3]: process started with pid [17452]

[INFO] [gzserver-4]: process started with pid [17454]

[INFO] [gzclient-5]: process started with pid [17456]

[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-6]: process started with pid [17458]

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490131501] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490360186] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490381050] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link_inertia

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490391845] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment flange

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490399416] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forearm_link

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490406305] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ft_frame

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490413635] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment shoulder_link

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490421409] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment tool0

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490428799] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment upper_arm_link

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490436151] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490443524] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wrist_1_link

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490450548] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wrist_2_link

[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713612084.490457038] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wrist_3_link

[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1713612085.095709302] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED

[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1713612085.095901463] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)

[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1713612085.115538974] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED

[joint_state_publisher_gui-1] [INFO] [1713612085.236196149] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...

[joint_state_publisher_gui-1] [INFO] [1713612085.246721477] [joint_state_publisher]: Centering

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612085.249944683] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612085.250382860] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description

[spawn_entity.py-6] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.

[spawn_entity.py-6]   warnings.warn(

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612085.252857047] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612085.263878060] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612085.264253333] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity

[joint_state_publisher_gui-1] [INFO] [1713612085.575955357] [joint_state_publisher]: Centering

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612086.019231594] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity

[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1713612086.307182072] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [ur_robot]

[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 17458]

[joint_state_publisher_gui-1] [INFO] [1713612088.418549565] [joint_state_publisher]: Centering

Here's a picture of it when I ran it with the launch file I created above:

